# How to define custom text theme in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to make my own text theme style?
I only find the default text theme like this but it's not enough.

```
textTheme: TextTheme(
  body1: TextStyle(),
  body2: TextStyle(),
  button: TextStyle(),
  caption: TextStyle(),
  display1: TextStyle(),
  display2: TextStyle(),
  display3: TextStyle(),
  display4: TextStyle(),
  headline: TextStyle(),
  overline: TextStyle(),
  subhead: TextStyle(),
  subtitle: TextStyle(),
  title: TextStyle(),
),
```

I want for example have a text with line through then some other have underline etc
I was thinking to override the `body2` for underline style then how to define another style for line through?

Kind Regards

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615933/flutter-define-custom-textstyles-for-use-throughout-the-app

Comment: Have you tried the copyWith method https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextTheme/copyWith.html

Comment: Wow I believe it is what I'm looking for... So @chemamolins I could accept your answer if you put an answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create a class to hold your style and then call it from anywhere in your app.

```
class CustomTextStyle {
  static TextStyle display5(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4.copyWith(fontSize: 192.0);
  }
}
```

And the use it as

```
Text(
   'Wow',
   style: CustomTextStyle.display5(context),
),
```

Look at question [Flutter: Define custom TextStyles for use throughout the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615933) that contains the complete answer referred here.

Answer (score 19):

Here is an alternative using the extension method with the lineThrough:

```
extension CustomStyles on TextTheme {
 TextStyle get error => const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough, fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
Text("your text", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.error)
```

Comment: just keep in mind that extensions follow the same privacy rules of the rest of dart, so if you declare it outside of where you need to use it, you'll need to import the file origin as well! More info can be found [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)

Answer (score 14):

Since the release of dart 2.7, you can also use an extension method:

```
extension CustomStyles on TextTheme {
  TextStyle get error {
    return TextStyle(
      fontSize: 18.0,
      color: Colors.red,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Text(error, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `TextStyle()` options for further customization. For the specs you need set the `decoration` option. For underlining:

```
TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline)
```

and for line through:

```
TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough)
```

Comment: Yes sure but I want to put it into Theme so I don't repeat the same over and over again and make maintenance easy to changes. I mean I need 1 style theme for underline another for line through while body1 and body2 already have their purposes. So how do I define a new set of theme?

Comment: @rxlky I don't understand. Assign either the `TextStyle` or the `TextTheme` to a separate variable then re-use it?

Comment: Afaik, using TextStyle only for each individual Text so it is repeated again and again. And using TextTheme how do I add new style? For example body3, body4?