# Flutter How to use a custom word in textTheme

Tags: flutter

I know I can create a customized theme with MaterialApp, but is it possible for me to use a word of my own instead of the reserved words?

For exemple:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  theme: ThemeData(
    // Define the default brightness and colors.
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
    accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],

    // Define the default font family.
    fontFamily: 'Georgia',

    // Define the default TextTheme. Use this to specify the default
    // text styling for headlines, titles, bodies of text, and more.
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      nameReview: TextStyle(fontSize: 72.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      textReview: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      dateReview: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontFamily: 'Hind'),
    ),
  )
);
```

for when I see in the construction of my review widget the code becomes more readable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define custom text theme in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774597/how-to-define-custom-text-theme-in-flutter)